# How to get Interior Mutability on a Copy type?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I have a few `Copy` types, and I really appreciate the handiness of them being `Copy`.

I would like one of those types to contain a mutable field, using Interior Mutability as in `cell::Cell`. There are probably other solutions for the problem I am trying to solve, but Interior Mutability is *cheap*. I like *cheap*.

However, [it turns out that `cell::Cell` is not `Copy`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20813), and from the comments is unlikely to become `Copy` as the maintainers fear this would be error-prone.

A comment by the OP is my current beacon of hope:

> It's not the absolute end of the world if it doesn't for my own data structures (since I can just make my own version of `Cell`)

Though I do not see how they purport to achieve this feat.

The core issue I have is that [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html):

- is mandatory to implement Interior Mutability,
- is not `Copy`.

Which seems to close the door to any hope of implementing a `CopyCell`, unless I am missing a trick (a way to `unsafe impl` the `Copy` trait?).

---

[MCVE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=820c948e608902a88da13edc93278ac7&version=stable):

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct HelloWorld(Cell<u32>);
```

> ```
>   |
> 3 | #[derive(Clone, Copy)]
>   |                 ^^^^
> 4 | struct HelloWorld(Cell<u32>);
>   |                   ---------- this field does not implement `Copy`
> ```

What should I replace `Cell` with for `HelloWorld` to be `Copy`?

---

*Note: at the moment, the only way I can see of achieving the desired outcome is to use a `&Cell<T>`; with all the lifetimes implications.*

Comment: so, just to be sure what you're asking, you want to be able to copy `Cell`, but *not* the value inside it, right ?

Comment: @Tigran That wouldn't make any sense. `Cell` doesn't provide shared ownership (unlike `Rc` or `Arc`) so in order to copy a `Cell`, you *must* copy the value inside it.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: agree, but that's what I understand from the question, which, rightfully, goes against language logic. I just wanted to clarify the point.

Comment: @Tigran: I want to `Copy` both. For what it's worth my usecase is for a `Cell<u32>` (which is why `&Cell` is irksome, as it triples the memory requirement).

Comment: @Tigran: I added a code excerpt to clarify my intended usage.

Comment: A [related issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/45683).

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a good reason that `UnsafeCell` doesn't implement `Copy`: it would be unsafe in the general case. *Reading* from an `UnsafeCell` is an unsafe operation, as shown by the `get` method's signature: it returns a raw pointer, and dereferencing a raw pointer is an unsafe operation. A copy would implicitly read the value, which could race with another thread writing to the same `UnsafeCell`. `Cell` doesn't have that race because it is `!Sync` (i.e. two threads can't access the same `Cell`).

Personally, I would just use [`Clone::clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#tymethod.clone) instead of messing with references. `Cell`'s `clone` is `#[inline]`, so it's highly likely that the call will be optimized away in release builds.

Comment: I kind of relate to reasoning behind refusing to support `Copy` on those types, but from other side it doesn't fill right, to completely erase it from the `Cell`. There is also discussion about it on [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/20199) link. There has to be a way to explicitly define it for a given type.

Comment: I am not worried about *performance*, only about *convenience*. `Clone` and `Copy` have the same cost, one is just much easier to use than the other.

Comment: You make a good point about `UnsafeCell`, but it does leave one in a quandary. Is there a way to *force* the implementation of `Copy` on a `MagicCell` despite the underlying `UnsafeCell` not being `Copy`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. No, there's no way to work around that validation in the compiler; [here's the code that implements that validation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4d2d3fc5dadf894a8ad709a5860a549f2c0b1032/src/librustc/ty/util.rs#L176-L209).